# No errors appears on the page in PHP even if display_error is set to on

Tags: php

I use php to built a website and I have an error 500 on a script when I am looking on the Chrome console but nothing appears on the webpage. I checked on the php.ini and the display_errors value is set to On

```
display_errors = On
```

I added on the top of my script

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

but still no error message.
Any help?

Comment: PHP errors aren't going to appear in the *JavaScript* console?  Are you looking at the source/network pane?

Comment: yes I am looking on the network pane, and click on the file. But i remember to have the content of the webpage with the error in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Find apache and php default log location (it changes according to your distribution and installation params), you should get to see errors there, not in chrome console

Answer (score 0):

Many PHP installations don't display fatal errors. However, you can register a shutdown function and log the fatal errors if you want:

```
function shutdownFunction()
{
    if ($error = error_get_last()) {
        // try logging here, but do not expose the error contents to the client
        header('PHP Fatal Error', true, 500);
    }
    if (session_id())) {
        session_write_close();
    }
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');
```